# PostgreSQL : Not able to write to file while inserting records to a table due to disc space constraint

Tags: postgresql

I am using postgresql 11. Due to lack of disc space in tablespace, I had to resort to the following steps:

1. Take the dump of the existing database in .sql format. Size was 6.8GB.
2. `DROP` the existing database.
3. Create a new `TABLESPACE` in a different location.
4. `CREATE` new database with same name `WITH` the new tablespace.
5. I verified whether the new Database is using the new tablespace from pgAdmin. It was seen that it is using the new tablespace.
6. I restored the dumped DB (in step 1) to this new DB using `psql -U dbuser -d my_db < /path/to/old_db.sql`

Then I wanted to `INSERT` or `UPDATE` large records (row count > 10000) and still I am getting the following error:

```
    '53100-could not write to file "pg_tblspc/226475/PG_11_201809051/pgsql_tmp/pgsql_tmp31551.109": No space left on device'
```

I peeped inside `/pgsql_temp/` and there is nothing. I checked inside PG_11_202809051 and there is a directory named 234705 and inside that there are several files including PG_VERSION. I checked with `du -sh` and the size of the this directory is coming 9.2GB. However in the newly created tablespace I have over 50GB space available.

What I am missing here?

P.S. : I have also ran the below sets of SQL query to check how much space is being used all tables.

```
select pg_size_pretty(pg_database_size('grse_procurement_acc'));
```

And I am getting 9.3GB.

Why the dump size and DB size are not matching?

Any guidance on the above two questions would be helpful.

Comment: Can you show the text of the insert or update that errors out, and the EXPLAIN of it?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem are temporary files. These files are created when an SQL statement needs more space from an operation than `work_mem` permits and live only for the duration of the statement. They get deleted as soon as the statement ends, which is why you don't see them any more after the operation has failed.

You'll have to figure out which operation causes all these temporary files to be written. For that, set `log_temp_files = 0` in `postgresql.conf`, reload PostgreSQL and try again. Then you should see the statement in the log.

Comment: From `pg_stat_database` I can see the size of temp files. Yes it is big. so how do I delete them? Please suggest.

Comment: You don't delete them, because they are no longer there. I described that in my answer.